# Profiles content check if set?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, profile

Using asp.net profiles, I've stored a complex type (class) and retrieved it. But it is returning a new object that is not initialized instead of null? Is this the expected behavior, if so how can I determine if I've saved data for the given user?

should be some easy points for someone to pick up..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think you're asking why there's a non-null profile data object for a user who you haven't stored data for yet?

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx#S4) might hopefully clear it up for you.  Some of the relevant bits:

> A user profile is a collection of
>   values that the ASP.NET 2.0 runtime
>   groups as public fields of a
>   dynamically generated class. The class
>   is derived from a system-provided
>   class and is extended with the
>   addition of a few new members. The
>   class doesn't have to be marked as
>   Serializable, however its contents are
>   persisted to the storage medium as
>   individual properties. The storage
>   occurs on a per-user basis and is
>   preserved until an administrator
>   deletes it.

And further down:

> When the application runs and a page
>   is displayed, ASP.NET dynamically
>   creates a profile object that contains
>   properly typed data and assigns the
>   current settings for the logged user
>   to the properties defined in the data
>   model. The profile object is added to
>   the current HttpContext object and
>   made available to pages through the
>   Profile property. Assuming that the
>   profile model has been defined to
>   store a list of links as a collection,
>   the following code snippet shows how
>   to retrieve the list of favorite links
>   that are created by a given user:
>
> ...
>
> This code assumes a Links property in
>   the profile object that references a
>   collection type. When the page is
>   loaded, Links and other properties are
>   initialized to contain the most
>   recently stored values; when the page
>   is unloaded their current contents are
>   stored to the persistent medium.

If you need to track whether a user has ever set profile data before, you might be able to use the [FindProfilesByUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.findprofilesbyusername.aspx) function to check to see if a profile exists before you log them in.

Comment: First, thank you for the suggestion. Correct, the question is why my objects are not-null. I don't like that the find function because that somewhat defeats the purpose. I'm thinking of adding a "dirtyflag" or save flagged to my objects.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but [UsingDefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingspropertyvalue.usingdefaultvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) tells you if the property value is coming from the user profile settings or if it's using a default. Another way you can get, kind of, the same result is using [Deserialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingspropertyvalue.deserialized?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Comment: I've never seen `UsingDefaultValue` be *true*. I can't work out why not as I would expect it not to be an actual bug. BTW, the doco states that the values only have to be the same, not that the sources of the values are diferent. That should make a *true* value even more likely.